# Outputting array data based on a dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I'm currently trying to log out 3 pieces of information from my program:

1. Position in the array
2. value associated with this position
3. The dictionary key value associated with this position

However, I think I've gotten myself confused about how this should be done. Could someone please look at my code to tell me what I'm doing wrong as it is not outputting my required information:

```
float[] foo_array = new float[dictionary.Count];
dictionary.Values.CopyTo(foo_array, 0);

Array.Sort(foo_array);

foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys)
{

    for( int i = 0; i < foo_array.Length; i++)
    {
      Debug.Log("Array position: " + i + " ARRAY VALUE : " + foo_array[i] +   " key value: " + key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand on "not outputting my required information" ? Is it outputting anything at all, or is it outputting something else than what you were expecting ? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is iterating over the dictionary for it's positions, and related keys and values.
You don't need to copy the keys to an array to do so:

```
var formatStrings =
    dictionary.Select((kvp, index) => 
        string.Format(
            "Position: {0} Key: {1} Value: {2}", index, kvp.Key, kvp.Value));

foreach (var formatString in formatStrings) 
{
    Debug.Log(formatString);
}
```

Comment: I'm placing the key values in an array as I need the 3 smallest values being sent over. As they values change over time, I need the array to constantly update itself so the first three positions in the array are the smallest values possible

Comment: you can do `dictionary.OrderBy(_ => _.Value).Select(....)` in order to keep the sorting. If you sort the array after copying the values, then the index positions will no longer correlate to the dictionary.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you, however, I need the three smallest values to plug into something else, I thought the easiest way to deal with to plug in array positions

Comment: In that case you would probably do `var toSend = dictionary.OrderBy(_ => _.Value).Take(3);` 
Does that answer your question? If so, please accept. Thank You.

Comment: Also, if you need to constantly keep the dictionary sorted, then I would suggest looking at [Sorted Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).